# How can I stop Microsoft Edge auto-populating quick links?

Tags: microsoft-edge

When I open a new tab in Microsoft Edge, there is a 'Quick Links' bar containing shortcuts to various web pages. I like this feature, but it seems to auto-populate with websites that I visit often. Is there a way to disable this auto population, while still retaining the bar?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it's been driving me nuts, and there may be an answer elsewhere, but I haven't found it. It's particularly annoying as you can just have the links you want in Chrome, but not here.

While noodling around, I may have found the answer.

If you have a link that you want to keep, click on the 3 dots to the right and above it, and one of the options is "Pin to page". Click on that, and that link will stay. Repeat for all other links you want to keep. Now when Edge adds new links on its own to Quicklinks, the links you want to keep will stay.

I haven't played with this enough to see whether it keeps the pinned link in the specific spot, or it moves it in the bar, or if there are any other issues, but try it.

See what you think.